# .NET Interop Memory Leak, strong handle cannot be dumped

Tags: c#, .net, com, windbg

I try to figure out an Memory Leak in my mixed VC++/C# application. Interop is done by com. I figured out the garbage collector does not clean up the managed Object LcUI.Portal.PortalMainForm. It is created and released in the native part of the application. But each time this is done an instance gets created and not cleaned up.

Here a sample output from windbg:

```
!dumpheap -type LcUI.Portal.PortalMainForm
 Address       MT     Size
234528ac 1dcf176c      652
```

!gcroot find the object referenced as (strong handle) on the HandleTable:

```
!gcroot -all 234528ac
HandleTable:
    02fd530c (strong handle)
    -> 234528ac LcUI.Portal.PortalMainForm
```

But I'm not able to get the handle info:

```
!handle 02fd530c
Could not duplicate handle 2fd530c, error 6
```

Because of the (strong handle) I believe a static self reference from LcUI.Portal.PortalMainForm to the instance of LcUI.Portal.PortalMainForm prevents cleanup by the gc. Or is this a misinterpretation?

Via !DumpObj /d 234528ac I did not find such a reference. How may I find who and where the handle is still held?

Comment: Using WinDbg for .NET, it's usually difficult to focus on one type/instance in general, because the issue (if there is) usually ties many instances together (for example this is a good example of global scrutiny https://codetaco.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/tracking-down-a-memory-leak-with-windbg/). It looks like you're using WinForms, you may want to check everything is Disposed and look particularly at events that are common with Winforms. Difficult to say more w/o some repro code.

Comment: AFAIK, SOS does not have a `!handle` command. It looks to me like you're trying to interpret that data as a kernel handle. The "strong handle" typically refers to a static variable.

Comment: Sorry but I wasn't able to stip my classes down to a small sample where the problem is reproducaable. 
If ```!handle``` is not working for managed handles hwo my I get more information on where the handle my hung? I did not find any static fields that my cause the problem. Also I deleted all events and the leak is still there.

Comment: Well, the static property needn't be yours. For example there is [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0#System_Windows_Forms_Application_OpenForms). If you just hide the window (make it invisible) and do not close it, it will probably still be in this list.

Comment: Very good hint, but Close was called correctly. I think it must a static property that is somehow done by the framework, but I have no glue how to figure out where.

Comment: Can you share a dump file? I could sign an NDA if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of debugging I found it out. It was the nativ windows handel that was hanging in the WinForms Framework which caused the memory leak.
This happened because in the OnClosing event the close was canceled but some method that was called fromt he event did also call close.
After I cleaned this state so there was no need to cancel the close the memory leak was gone.